# How to produce readable Truth Table test data in Junit

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to model logic circuits with Java.  I'd like to be able to use test data that looks a bit like a truth table, without having to one assertion for each possible combination of input and output.

My first thought was to use the parameterized runner from junit - this allows me to do something like this:

```java
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class AndGateTest {

  @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: Input: a={0}, b={1}, q={2}")
  public static Collection<Object[]> truthTable(){
    Object[][] andGateTruthTable = {
        {false, false, false},
        {true, true, true},
        {true, false, false},
        {false, true, false}
    };
    return Arrays.asList(andGateTruthTable);
  }

  private final boolean a;
  private final boolean b;
  private final boolean q;
  private AndGate and;

  public AndGateTest(boolean a, boolean b, boolean q ) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.q = q;
  }

  @Before
  public void setup() { and = new AndGate(); }

  @Test
  public void testWithTruthTable() { assertEquals( q, and.input(a, b)); }
```

This works fine, but I wonder if there's a way to make the Truth Table more readable?  For example, using Cucumber I could have a data table with a list of maps.  I'm happy to use that, as I'm pretty familiar with Gherkin, but I wondered what other approaches there might be?